# Curve in a product of tori

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry

Consider the curve $\gamma:\mathbb R\to (\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)^n$ given by $$\gamma(t)=(a_1t,\ldots,a_nt)$$ for generic real numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. Is the image of $\gamma$ dense in $(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)^n$?

Comment: What do you mean by generic? If I set $a_1=\dots=a_n=0$, then the image will not be dense!

Comment: Do you know a criterion for denseness when, say, $n = 2$?

Comment: Yes, for $n=2$ and higher $n$, I think it suffices that the $a_n$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the answer seems to be yes, by [Kronecker's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem).